# error saving comment ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, comments

I'm using the simple_form gem but I tried doing it without the gem as well and still get the same error. so I don't think it's the syntax, I tried it in haml as well and same error.

UPDATE:

New I fixed the issues thanks to a comment below but now I'm getting the "error saving comment" form my comments controller below at the end

I'm following this tut http://twocentstudios.com/blog/2012/11/15/simple-ajax-comments-with-rails/

comments/_form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for comment, :remote => true do |f| %>
 <%= f.input :body, :input_html => { :rows => "2" }, :label => false %>
 <%= f.input :commentable_id, :as => :hidden, :value => comment.commentable_id %>
 <%= f.input :commentable_type, :as => :hidden, :value => comment.commentable_type %>
 <%= f.button :submit, :class => "btn btn-primary", :disable_with => "Submitting…" %>
<% end %>
```

comments/_comment.html.erb

```
<div class="comment" id="comment-<%= comment.id %>">
<hr/>
 <%= link_to "×", comment_path(comment), :method => :delete, :remote => true, :confirm => "Are you sure you want to remove this comment?", :disable_with => "×", :class => 'close' %>
 <h4>
  <%= comment.user.username %>
  <small>
  <%= comment.updated_at %>
  </small>
</h4>
<p>
<%= comment.body %>
</p>
</div>
```

comments/show.html.erb

```
 <%= @user.username %>
   <div class="comments">
    <h2>Comments</h2>
```

## edited this line: @comment to :comment

```
    <%= render :partial => 'comments/form', :locals => { :comment => @new_comment } %>
    <%= render :partial => 'comments/comment', :collection => @comments, :as => :comment %>
 </div>
```

users/show.html.erb

```
# ....all other code
 <h1>
  <%= @user.username %>
 </h1>


 <h2>Comments</h2>
```

## same edit in this line

```
 <%= render :partial => 'comments/form', :locals => { :comment => @new_comment } %>
 <%= render :partial => 'comments/comment', :collection => @comments, :as => :comment %>
```

commentsController

```
  def create
    @comment_hash = params[:comment]
    @obj =   @comment_hash[:commentable_type].constantize.find(@comment_hash[:commentable_id])
    # Not implemented: check to see whether the user has permission to create a comment on this object
    @comment = Comment.build_from(@obj, current_user, @comment_hash[:body])
    if @comment.save
      render :partial => "comments/comment", :locals => { :comment => @comment }, :layout => false, :status => :created
    else
      render :js => "alert('error saving comment');"
    end
  end
```

comments.js.coffee

```
  # comments.js.coffee
  jQuery ->
  # Create a comment
  $(".comment-form")
    .on "ajax:beforeSend", (evt, xhr, settings) ->
      $(this).find('textarea')
        .addClass('uneditable-input')
        .attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    .on "ajax:success", (evt, data, status, xhr) ->
      $(this).find('textarea')
        .removeClass('uneditable-input')
        .removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled')
        .val('');
      $(xhr.responseText).hide().insertAfter($(this)).show('slow')


      $(document)
    .on "ajax:beforeSend", ".comment", ->
      $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.5)
    .on "ajax:success", ".comment", ->
      $(this).hide('fast')
    .on "ajax:error", ".comment", ->
      $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1)
```

Comment: Shouldn't `:locals => { comment => @new_comment }` be `:locals => { :comment => @new_comment }` in `comments/show.html.erb`? Similarly for `:locals => { @comment => @new_comment }` in `users/show.html.erb`.

Comment: changed both to :comment but now I get error saving comming, I'm using ajax

Comment: But the form is properly generated, right?

Comment: yes the form is properly generated thanks

Comment: What AJAX problem are you having? Shouldn't everything after `jQuery ->` in your `comments.js.coffee` be indented one level?

Comment: fixed that but now i'm getting `ExecJS::RuntimeError in Devise::Sessions#new` and `[stdin]:9:3: error: unexpected .
  .on "ajax:success", (evt, data, status, xhr) ->`

Comment: Looks okay to me. Delete that CoffeeScript and start adding it back bit by bit until it breaks again I guess. Fix the indentation after `$(document)` too.

Comment: ok fixed but now I get the "error saving comments" from the comments controller create method